# How to unit test a helper funtion call in a collection in C# using Mock

Tags: c#, moq

I 'm new to unit testing and I want to create a unit test for the following code:

```
   public IEnumerable<Product> CreateProductList(
       IEnumerable<int> productsIds, IEnumerable<Product> products)
    {
        var productsList = productsIds.GroupJoin(
            inner: products, 
            outerKeySelector: x => x, 
            innerKeySelector: y => y.Id,
            resultSelector: (x, y) => _productServiceHelper.
            FactoryProduct(x, y.FirstOrDefault(k => k.Id == x))).ToList();

        return productsList;
    }
```

The unit test that I have written so far is trying to use MockSequence but unsuccessfully:

```
   [Test, TestCaseSource(nameof(TestCases_CreateProductList_SomeMissingIds))]
    public void CreateProductList_SomeMissingIds_ReturnListContainingMissingOnes
        (IEnumerable<int> listWithRequiredProductsIds, IEnumerable<Product> listMissingIds,
        IEnumerable<Product> expectedListContainingAllRequired)
    {
        //_mockProductServiceHelper.InSequence(sequence).Setup(x => 
        //    x.FactoryProduct(It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<Product>())).Returns(()=> expectedListContainingAllRequire(x => x));

        //expectedListContainingAllRequired.ToList()
           // .Select(x => _mockProductServiceHelper.InSequence(sequence)
                       // .Setup(y => y.FactoryProduct(It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<Product>()))
                    //.Returns(x));
        //expectedListContainingAllRequired.
        var result = _productService.CreateProductList(listWithRequiredProductsIds,
                        listMissingIds);


        var jsonResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
        var jsonExpectedListContainingAllRequired = JsonConvert.SerializeObject
                                        (expectedListContainingAllRequired);
        //_mockProductServiceHelper.Verify(x => x.FactoryProduct(),Times.Once);

        //Assert.That(result.Count(), Is.EqualTo(expectedListContainingAllRequired.Count()));
        Assert.That(result.Count(), Is.EqualTo(expectedListContainingAllRequired.Count()));
        Assert.That(jsonResult, Is.EqualTo(jsonExpectedListContainingAllRequired));
    }

    public static IEnumerable TestCases_CreateProductList_SomeMissingIds
    {
        get
        {
            yield return DataCases_CreateProductList_SomeMissingIds(
                new List<int> { 1, 2 }, new List<int> { 1 });
            yield return DataCases_CreateProductList_SomeMissingIds(
                new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, new List<int> { 1, 2 });
        }
    }

    private static TestCaseData DataCases_CreateProductList_SomeMissingIds
        (IEnumerable<int> productIDs, IEnumerable<int> productObjects)
    {
        var productListObjects = productObjects.Select(CreateMockObject);

        var expectedProductList = productIDs.Select(CreateMockObject);

    return new TestCaseData(productIDs, productListObjects, expectedProductList);
    }

    private static Product CreateMockObject(int x)
    {
        return new Product
        {
            Category = new Category { Id = 1, Name = "padrao" },
            Name = "Product " + x,
            Description = "Any Description " + x,
            Creation = DateTime.Now.Date,
            Launch = DateTime.Now.Date,
            Price = x * 2
    };
    }
```

I have tried so many things but apparently nothing works. I left some paths that I tried to follow commented.

Does anybody have a suggestion or an example that helps to accomplish testing my method?

Comment: Here you don't need any mock, just prepare test data which should produce expected result and use them in test. No mock, but real lists of int and Product.